# How to put_object() to specific folder inside S3 bucket from R?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

We can move a file to S3 like so

```
library(aws.s3)
saveRDS(iris, "iris.RDS")
put_object("iris.RDS", object="iris.RDS", bucket="mybucket", acl=c("public-read"))
```

Instead of moving the file to the root of the S3 bucket, how can I place it inside a folder in the S3 bucket?

#### What I've tried

I've tried the obvious solution, prepending the folder name to the object, but it errors

```
put_object("iris.RDS", object="myfolder/iris.RDS", bucket="mybucket", acl=c("public-read"))
```

#### Notes

- I have already created a folder manually through the browser, so it's ready to go, I just need to know how to put files there

Comment: What error? your trial is the correct one.

Comment: @Lamanus thanks. The docs confirm this. I just realised in the call to put_object() in my code I had `../` (since that's where the files are stored locally). Silly. Appreciate the help.